how to import the required Python library (ansible-pylibssh) redhat
I keep getting failed to import python library ansible-pylibssh with redhat while trying to run a simple cisco playbook.
Failed to import the required Python library (ansible-pylibssh) on devc-ansible-01's Python /usr/bin/python3.12. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"}
This is my play book:
---

- name: show version
  hosts: routers
  gather_facts: false
  connection: network_cli

  vars:
    ansible_network_os: ios

  tasks:
    - name: run the show verison
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - sh ip interfave brief

Inside my ansible.cfg file is this:
interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python3.
ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
host_key_checking =False

This is the output of my ansible --version:
ansible --version ansible [core 2.16.3] config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules'] ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible ansible collection location = /home/user/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
and this is the output of ansible-yislbssh:
[ansible-01 playbooks]$ pip3 show ansible-pylibssh
Name: ansible-pylibssh
Version: 1.2.0.post4
Summary: Python bindings for libssh client specific to Ansible use case
Home-page: https://github.com/ansible/pylibssh
Author: Ansible, Inc.
Author-email: info+github/ansible/pylibssh@ansible.com
License: LGPLv2+
Location: /home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:


I don't know why it's failing.
I have installed the packages that the machine is complaining about and even added the interpreter but the playbook still fails.

I see in pip3 show output Location: /home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages, but your Ansible uses /usr/bin/python3.12. In general you can start Python ( /usr/bin/python3.12 in your case) and then execute import ansible-pylibssh) for a test
